# Javascript Remoting through HTML in salesforce

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

I want to call method in an apex class in header part of customer portal which is a HTML page (not a VF page).

Is it possible to access apex class method in such a way, If yes, then how to start on this?

Comment: Only HTML or Javascript is a possible way ?

Comment: But how? can you provide some reference

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts Check this out. This is a very useful blog.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an external page and you are trying to access an apex method. For this the apex class must be a web service class. This means a global class exposed. like this

```
 global class AccountPlan {

   webservice static Plan createAccountPlan(Plan vPlan) {

           //add logic here......
   }
 }
```

And from your HTML page you can call this method using AJAX calls.

Hope this was useful

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

**VF :**

```
<div id="header">
    <script language="javascript">
        var myControllerMethod = '{!myControllerMethod}';
    </script>
</div>
```

**Controller :**

```
 public with sharing class MyClass {
        public String getMyControllerMethod () {
            //Do some stuff

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry But its not working. How will you identify the class for the method "getMyControllerMethod"

Comment: If it's a VisualfForce page, you may have the `controller` field in your `<apex:page>` tag. Here it's `<apex:page controller="MyClass">`

Comment: In my understanding the question is not about Visualforce, but places where you can upload/configure pure HTML. In a VF page you can reference by controllername.methodname, but can that be done in non-VF pages on the platform?

Comment: No i am not having VF page i am doing it on HTML page. However i found the solution https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_and_ajax.htm